# AngularJS $resource in a simple factory

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-resource

I am trying to learn AngularJS in baby steps and I'm falling down a lot. In my controller, this works:

```
var svc = $resource('MyService/dimensions');
$scope.NumDen = svc.query();
```

When I try to put it in a simple factory the console lights up with TypeError: Cannot read property 'query' of undefined

My factory is defined like:

```
app.factory('myFactory', ['$resource', function ($resource) {
    return $resource('MyService/dimensions');
}]);
```

I'm trying to call my factory:

```
var svc = myFactory();
$scope.NumDen = svc.query();
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: The factory is already instantiated when you inject it into the controller, so you just need to call the query method like this: `$scope.NumDen = myFactory.query();`.

Comment: You are correct. Thank you very much. How can I mark this question answered?

Comment: I can post it as an answer but @svlapin has answered the same so you can accept his answer. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call your factory to get it instantiated. So just:

```
var svc = myFactory; // no invocation
$scope.NumDen = svc.query();
```